# Cannot download patch from Embarcadero web site

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a possible Delphi bug (oh, damn it, I used again the word 'bug') and I think this QC might help me: 
[ID: 28269, IDE hangs when following "uses" links](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/28269)

When I want to download it it says that:

> To download this, you must have
>   registered: Your existing free
>   membership

And I have one (I am a Delphi Pro edition customer). I can download all other updates and patches except this one. But I don't think its a problem with my membership because the download size is:

> Download      0 bytes

and then in the right column:

> Size: 0 bytes
>   Updated on Mon, 21 Mar
>   2011 08:34:52 GMT Originally uploaded
>   on Mon, 21 Mar 2011 08:34:52 GMT

Can anybody try to see if the link its working or not?

Comment: There is no patch where. Looks like the author Micha Kleidt made a mistake by posting the above information to cc (code central) instead of qc (quality central).

Comment: Thanks Serg. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it and close this question.

Comment: I don't think that "I tried to find something on a website" is a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no patch there. Looks like the author Micha Kleidt made a mistake by posting the above information to cc (code central) instead of qc (quality central).